# cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 'x.xx.xxx.xx' port 9090: Connection refused

Tags: php, curl, xmpp, openfire, guzzle

cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 'x.xx.xxx.xx' port 9090: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://x.xx.xxx.xx:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users

Hello folks, I am using gnello/php-openfire-restapi to manage an Openfire instance by sending a REST/HTTP request to the server.
It is properly working on localhost means it is creating users on Openfire but not working on the server host.

Comment: 'myip' is not a correct URL or IP.

Comment: replace myip with you actual IP address; finding IP address depends on your OS/version.

Answer (score 0):

This error is showing because port 9090 is blocked. Just Remove server-side port number 9090.